# Git-Bash unusable while running a process (Such as Sublime Text 3)?

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, git-bash

I finally got Git-Bash to open a file/folder with Sublime Text BUT while sublime text is open, I cannot issue any new commands in Bash and when closing the terminal it in turn closes Sublime Text.

I want to be able to open a file or folder with sublime text using git-bash but for them not to be ..connected I guess? I don't know.. it seems like when it runs the text editor it's locked in the process of running the editor instead of just opening it.

Same thing with using live-server. 
Do I just have to run multiple terminals? 1 to issue commands and 1 for each process I'm running like Sublime and live-server?

Comment: How are you starting Sublime from the bash prompt?

Comment: I set up an Alias in ~/.bashcr or whachamacallit file to the sublime directory with an alias of "subl" following multiple guides I founds on here.
In the bash I just put "subl filename.suffix"

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed not have to open multiple terminals to do what you want; executing Sublime should drop you back into the terminal allowing you to execute additional commands.

There are a couple of ways for you to be able to access Sublime from a command prompt.

The first would be to modify the system `PATH` to include the installation directory of Sublime. Once you do that, you can execute `subl` directly (from Git Bash, a standard `cmd` prompt, Cmder, and so on) so long as you open the console window ***after*** you update the `PATH`.

The second is to set up an alias that executes the command for you, in which case your alias would be named something like `subl` and it would include the full path to the appropriate executable so that executing the alias executes the command directly.

If you use the first method, then the only reason that `subl` should remain in the foreground in the terminal when you launch it is if you include the `-w` command line argument to tell it to `wait`; you would do this for example if you were using it as the `EDITOR` for `git` commit messages and so on, where the commit is paused until you finish editing the commit message.

If you use the second method above (the alias) then you also need to be careful about what you set the `alias` to execute.

In particular, on Windows and MacOS, Sublime ships with both an executable for Sublime itself (`sublime_text.exe` on Windows, `Sublime Text` on MacOS) as well as an executable named `subl.exe` (Windows) or `subl` (MacOS) for use in the terminal. Although both of them outwardly do the same thing how they do it is subtly different.

The full binary (e.g. `sublime_text.exe`) is actually Sublime, so running it runs Sublime, and much like any program you execute it remains running and the terminal prompt doesn't return control back to you until the program is completed.

The `subl` binary is a small wrapper application which sends a message to the running copy of Sublime to tell it to open the file, folder, etc and then it exits immediately (unless you tell it to `-w`ait); if Sublime is not running yet, it launches Sublime first, then sends the message.

On Linux, there is only a single `sublime_text` binary that ships which acts like `subl`; it launches Sublime if it needs to, sends a command to tell the running instance what to do, and then terminates. If you are using a packaged version of Sublime, it also includes `subl` command for you to execute, but this is just a shell script that invokes `sublime_text` directly.

Answer (score 0):

try adding '&' after 'subl'. it works for me